# Xamarin connection string

Tags: c#, mysql, sql-server, xamarin, xamarin.android

Im new to Xamarin and am trying to connect to a SQL Server Database which is located on my PC for a Xamarin Android application.
But the connection breaks every time at the connection.open line. I know the connection string credentials are correct as it works in a Windows form project. 
What is the correct way to state a SqlConnection in Xamarin or how can i go about connecting without using a web service?

Comment: I don't know why you are not, but please consider making web/rest service and make connection between your mobile app and database through that service.

Comment: Could you possibly advise how to go about doing that? The only reason Im not doing it is because I have never done it before and time is limited.

Comment: you almost certainly don't want ppl to figure out your connection string by decompiling your apk and use that to have full access to your DB

Comment: yes, this is very bad practice, it will hurt you badly

Comment: Take a look at this, after this tutorial you will be able to create your own simple web api. Basically communication will be like this: Your mobile app willl make request to web api, web api is talking with your db, and returning some response to your mobile client in json format, you can deserilize that json and show data in your mobile app. Tutorial for webapi implemenation part.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/first-web-api?view=aspnetcore-2.1

Answer (score 1):

In order to access your local host from an Android, use the address 10.0.2.2 in the connection string. The emulator sets up it's own network, and this address will allow you to connect to the local machine where SQL Server is running. If you're using a Genymotion emulator, you may need to use 10.0.3.2.